How can I add several Simple Gantt Charts into a Simple Gantt Chart container in SAPUI5?
I am trying to add multiple sap.gantt.simple.GanttChartWithTable dynamically into a Gantt Chart Container. I have defined the empty Gantt chart container in my XML view and I want to create multiple sap.gantt.simple.GanttChartWithTable in my JavaScript controller and add them to the Gantt chart container.
I get the following error: **TypeError: **Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getRowMode')
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e is null
_updateRowHeightInExpandModel GanttChartWithTable-dbg.js:3632

I have the following code:
`        <gnt2:GanttChartContainer id="ganttContainer">
            <gnt2:toolbar>
<gnt2:ContainerToolbar id="toolbar1" design="Auto" showBirdEyeButton="true" showLegendButton="true" ganttSidePanel="onGanttSidePanel" 
                showSearchButton="false" showDisplayTypeButton="true"
 
                </gnt2:ContainerToolbar>
            </gnt2:toolbar>
                >
        </gnt2:GanttChartContainer>`

JavaScript Controller:
 onInit: function () {
                var oGanttContainer = this.getView().byId("ganttContainer");
                var oGanttChart = new sap.gantt.simple.GanttChartWithTable(
                );
                oGanttContainer.addGanttChart(oGanttChart);
},

If I try as follows, I get the same error:
var oGanttChart = new GanttChartWithTable({
enableChartOverflowToolbar: true
});

oGanttContainer.addGanttChart(oGanttChart);


